Upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 Frozen
I made the mistake of using the upgrade prompt to attempt to upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04. I also made the mistake of failing to back up all my files before doing so. I took the risk because I was in a hurry, and all prior upgrades went smoothly. I was not aware of all the upgrade warnings in the groups, including AskUbuntu here, as I should have been.
The upgrade got as far as the "Installing the upgrades" step where the progress bar froze at 20% for two hours now. It appears the upgrade has failed. What is the best forward from here? I hope I can avoid a 24.04 clean install after recovering my files using Ubuntu Live.
My file system is zFS, with native zFS encryption. The OS resides on Raided 1 Mirrored NVME memory, and all subdirectories of /home is on a pair of RAID q Mirrored hard drives.
I have not attempted to reboot. I doubt at this point a reboot will be successful. Dolphin, and Nautilus, and the terminal emulator, do not launch anymore. Firefox does still launch and it is what I am using now to post this message. Until a decision is made on what do do next I will leave my computer powered up in the state it is in. I have a backup computer I can still use.
